# The figurative meaning of the word exotic

Tags: word-meaning, figurative-language

The words *exotic*, as it seems, is somehow related to the word *exit*; This justifies it's literal meaning which could be found everywhere.

What I'm looking for is the figurative meaning of the word. Like when we talk about the exotic way of doing something or exotic examples of something.

To my mind, in these cases *exotic* only means *strange* or *weird*. Am I right? Furthermore, doesn't it sound more positive than the above "meanings" (regardless of the context and in the usual situations)?

Thanks for your time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure the usage you're talking about is "figurative." Yes, if you want to be literally literal about the meaning of the word "literal," then a literal meaning should be closely tied to a word's etymology. But *exotic*'s relationship to *exit* is that they both [come from *exo* meaning "outside."](https://www.etymonline.com/word/exotic) That could be outside one's country, or simply outside of normal experience. Scientists talk about [exotic forms of matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exotic_matter), and they certainly don't mean that it has anything to do with distant lands.

Comment: Thanks for your response and +1. Now it really makes scence when I think about "exotic" as "strange." Because as you mentioned above, this meaning also comes from the root "exo." So we could relate the "literal" meaning to both of them. I think this misunderstanding comes from my original languge which these two words seem to have completely different meanings.